# pandas inconsistent api's for datetime?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I know `pandas` is really good at handling `datetimes` and some other aspects of series manipulation but this seems likes inconsistency or a bug.

```
timestart = (pd.to_datetime('21:00:00')+pd.offsets.Minute(-10)).time()
print timestart
print pd.to_datetime(timestart)+pd.offsets.Minute(10)

<ipython-input-353-1f1775aff24b> in <module>()
      1 timestart = (pd.to_datetime('21:00:00')+pd.offsets.Minute(-10)).time()
      2 print timestart
----> 3 print pd.to_datetime(timestart)+pd.offsets.Minute(10)
      4 #print timeend
```

I know somewhere deep down in the manual I would find the right approach, but this should be very simple to call!

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.time' and 'Minute'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print pd.to_datetime(timestart.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))+pd.offsets.Minute(10)
2015-03-27 21:00:00
```

You are passing in a datetime.time object (timestart), instead of a str.